# android itext using assets fonts and utf-8 text

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I'm trying to create pdf files in my android application using [www.itextpdf.com](http://www.itextpdf.com) , but i'm confused to using font from my assets

**Problem 1**

1- using my .TTF font that stored in my application assets , i always used TypeFace but now itext want me a "Font variable"

the syntax is like this :

```
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 18);
```

but it's no C:/ in android !

**Problem 2**

when i add a UTF-8 paragraph like Arabic or Persian , itext add nothing in PDF file

Comment: Have you tried http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html#createFont(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20byte[],%20byte[]) ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue, but I found the answer in another post that can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858760/cyrillic-letters-not-displaying-in-pdf-generated-with-itext-in-android).

Pretty much, what you are going to want to do is something similar to this:

```
BaseFont urName = BaseFont.createFont("assets/subFolder/fontName.TTF", "UTF-8",BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font urFontName = new Font(urName, 12);
```

Comment: It's not working getting IOException
java.io.IOException: assets/fonts/brandon_light.otf not found as file or resource.

Comment: This is the only working solution after struggling for hours... thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same  as you mention regarding exception. By using try{} catch(IOException | DocumentException ie){} this can be fixed.